# No puedo 'acceder' o 'seleccionar' el elemento img de mi HTML en un archivo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero seleccionar las imágenes con el tag img de HTML en mi archivo JavaScript pero por alguna razón no puedo, luego quiero hacer que clickeando en el body se le asigne una clase, pero ni siquiera puedo llegar a eso porque me tira un error con el "add" que imagino que es porque no sabe que 'leer', adjunto imagen del error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi código:

```
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
const pageBody = document.querySelector('body');

pageBody.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    imgs.classList.add('hidden');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

No se que tan bien esté autoresponder mi pregunta, pero investigando me di cuenta que es con un for, por si a alguien le sirve...

EDIT: Dejo el código en forma de código como tal y no de imágen, perdon si no puedo explicarlo y para explicarlo mal prefiero no hacerlo, soy algo nuevo practicando programación

EDIT EXPLICACIÓN: Se utiliza un ciclo for ya que en la constante imgs se estan guardando las imagenes y esta se convierte en un array, por lo cual para acceder a sus elementos hay que acceder mediante su indice, sabiendo que se accede de la forma imgs[i]. Con cada iteracion del ciclo for la variable i aumenta en 1 comenzando desde 0 y esta variable se usa para acceder a cada imagen guardada en la constante imgs. Finalmente el ciclo dejara de iterar cuando la variable i llegue a la misma cantidad de elementos guardados en el array.(No soy muy bueno para explicar...)

```
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
const pageBody = document.querySelector('body');

pageBody.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].classList.add('hidden')
    }
    
});
```

Comment: No coloques una imagen, coloca el código y explícalo para que los demás en un futuro puedan usar tu respuesta.

Comment: @JosueVargas ahi lo dejé en forma de código, aunque no puedo explicarlo, gracias por la recomendación y el aviso!

Comment: Añadi la explicacion como pude :)